# GAE: Way to get reference to an HttpSession from its ID?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets, httpsession

Under Google App Engine any object that you want to store in a [`HttpSession`](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSession.html) has to implement `Serializable`, and all of its fields have to be serializable, because an instance running in GAE might be migrated from one JVM to another.  This means that if I want to store a `FooBar` instance into an `HttpSession` I can't have a field in it pointing back to the `HttpSession`.

However, I *can* store the ID returned by `getId()`.  According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1251339/how-to-obtain-an-httpsession-object-from-sessionid) the ability to get a session from its ID has been depreciated for security reasons, but the GAE implementation is different.  According to [this blog post](http://blog.stringbuffer.com/2009/04/http-sessions-and-google-app-enginej.html) you can use the ID to get the DataStore entity representing the `HttpSession`, but I want a reference to the Java object, not the underlying data being used to migrate it between JVMs.

So, is there any way to do what I want?

Comment: Okay, so i had to read your question like three times or so to understand what you're trying to accomplish. However i still cannot see a practical use for what you're asking. If you store your `FooBar` object in your `HttpSession` with `#setAttribute(name, obj)`  you can get that object from your session any time (while in that session). Why do you want to create a circular reference when you will always refer to the `FooBar` object via its parent `HttpSession`? When you don't have the session object you should not be able to access any data associated with it. So why break session security?

Answer (score 3):

[Relevant paragraph from your link:](http://blog.stringbuffer.com/2009/04/http-sessions-and-google-app-enginej.html)

> A Datastore entity of kind "_ah_SESSION" is created for each new
>   HttpSession. The entity key is "_ahs" + session.getId(). Each
>   _ah_SESSION entity has two properties "_values" and "_expires".
>
> The "_values" property is simply the serialized byte[] representation
>   of a HashMap that includes the the session data.

So what you can do is as follows:

```java
// When putting FooBar to session
FooBar fooBar;
HttpSession session;
session.setAttribute("fooBar", fooBar);
```

And, on the other side:

```java
// When getting session from datastore
DatastoreService datastore = DatastoreServiceFactory.getDatastoreService();
Key sessionKey = KeyFactory.createKey("_ah_SESSION", sessionId);
Entity sessionEntity = datastore.get(sessionKey);
byte[] sessionBytes = sessionEntity.getProperty("_values");

ByteArrayInputStream byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(sessionBytes);
ObjectInputStream objectInputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
Map<?, ?> sessionMap = (Map) objectInputStream.readObject();
FooBar restoredFooBar = (FooBar) sessionMap.get("fooBar");
```

I wrote the code from memory, so please test it in production first and add standard things like cast check, but the general idea is the same.

Comment: I've documented this approach to resolve a problem with losing session data, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51014992/google-app-engine-session-loses-attribute